# Как правильно поменять IP адрес IPv4 с помощью команды netsh?

Tags: bat, командная-строка

Ввожу в командной строке:
    netsh interface ipv4 set address ethernet static 192.168.88.2 255.255.255.0
Пишет: "Элемент не найден". Что я делаю не так?

Comment: А у Вас сетевой интерфейс так и называется "ethernet"?

Comment: @Yaant Спасибо, я понял в чем моя ошибка.